# How do you get integer values in an NSPoint to display as integer rather than as decimal

Tags: swift

How do you get integer values in an NSPoint to display as integer rather than as decimal?

```
let temp:NSPoint = NSMakePoint(5,7)

print(temp.x) . // displays 5.0
```

I only want it to display 5, not 5.0

Comment: `print(Int(temp.x))`

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> How do you get integer values in an `NSPoint` to display as integer rather than as decimal.

This question may be based upon a false premise. The parameters you supply to [`NSMakePoint(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1391309-nsmakepoint) are actually `CGFloat` (as are the the underlying properties, `x` and `y`). So although you supplied integers, but Swift stores them as `CGFloat` for `x` and `y`, regardless.

So, the question is “How do you display the `CGFloat` properties of a `NSPoint` without any fractional digits?”

Certainly, as others have suggested, you can create an integer from the `CGFloat` properties with `Int(point.x)`, etc., but I might suggest that you really might want want to just display these `CGFloat` without decimal places. There are a bunch of ways of doing this.

Consider:

```
let point = NSPoint(x: 5000, y: 7000)
```

You can use `NSMakePoint`, too, but this is a little more natural in Swift.

Then to display this without decimal places, you have a few options:

1. In macOS, [`NSStringFromPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1391122-nsstringfrompoint) will generate the full `CGPoint` without decimal places:

   ```
   print(NSStringFromPoint(point))             // "{5000, 7000}"
   ```
2. You can use [`String(format:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126742-init), using a format string that explicitly specifies no decimal places:

   ```
   print(String(format: "%.0f", point.x))      // "5000"
   ```
3. You can use [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) and specify the `minimumFractionDigits`:

   ```
   let formatter = NumberFormatter()
   formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
   formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
   print(formatter.string(for: point.x)!)      // "5,000"
   ```

   Needless to say, you can save that formatter and you can use it repeatedly, as needed, if you want to keep your code from getting too verbose.
4. If you’re just logging this to the console, you can use [Unified Logging](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) with `import os.log` and then do:

   ```
   os_log("%.0f", point.x)                      // "5000"
   ```